# Cypress :: How to click on an image by selecting its alt value?

Tags: cypress

I need to select an image which is inside of a button. The problem is that there are six similar images and they do not have any unique identifier, except their alt message and source. Here is the code I am working with.

```
<div class="dropup-content" style="height: auto; max-height: 1000px;">
  <button type="button">
    <img src="images/en_US.png" alt="English" style="width: 45px; height: 30px;">
  </button>
  <button type="button">
    <img src="images/nb_NO.png" alt="Norwegian" style="width: 45px; height: 30px;">
  </button>
  <button type="button">
    <img src="images/fi_FI.png" alt="Finnish" style="width: 45px; height: 30px;">
  </button>
  <button type="button">
    <img src="images/fr_FR.png" alt="French" style="width: 45px; height: 30px;">
  </button>
  <button type="button">
    <img src="images/nl_BE.png" alt="Dutch" style="width: 45px; height: 30px;">
  </button>
  <button type="button">
    <img src="images/de_DE.png" alt="German" style="width: 45px; height: 30px;">
  </button>
</div>
```

Now, if I need to select the button with the alt value `Swedish`, how would I do it? For example, I can get the first one using this code:

```
cy.get('.dropup-content').first().click()
```

However, the problem is that the sequence comes randomly every time. So I can not rely on the `first()` or `next()` methods. Is there any way in Cypress to click on the button with image attribute `Swedish`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this like:

```js
cy.get('[alt="Swedish"]').click()
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```js
cy.get('button[alt="Swedish"]').click()
```

But if you have a control on how those buttons are created, I'd suggest you should add `data-cy` tag to them and then access them by

```js
cy.get('button[data-cy="Swedish"]').click()
```

Read why in [best practices docu](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html)